# Magento 2 checkout index, remove shipping info

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, template

In the checkout step, checkout_index_index, I'm wondering if anyone knows how to remove a column from the shipping options table (specifically the rightmost one)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Methods are listed on this template :

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

You can make an override in your theme :

> app/design/frontend/THEME/VARIATION/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping.html

Put the content of the original file and make the changes you want.

Be sure to disable your browser cache because .html files are stored inside.